# Не могу сложить Char с числом - ошибка несовместимости типов

Tags: delphi, строки, pascal

Прога выдает ошибку, мол типы не совместимы, хотя мои знания мне подсказывают что они совместимы, по крайней мере так должно быть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Типы действительно несовместимы - `ch` это чар(символ). В зависимости от платформы он может быть AnsiChar (1 байт) или WideChar (2 байта) или вообще Unicode (от 1 до 4 байт). В случае с AnsiChar, например, в свойствах строки указывается кодировка.

Повторюсь, Char это "буква", и она никак не может быть совместима с "числом".

В ранних версиях Delphi это все работало, т.к. по умолчанию все строки были AnsiString и кодировка задавалась на уровне приложения (Win1252 например).  Этим все пользовались и строка зачастую заменяла собой `array of byte`. Сейчас же, приложения перешли на Unicode и нельзя безопасно полагать, что строка это массив байтов.

В вашей программе необходимо написать *КАК* именно вы хотите преобразовать букву в число. Например это может быть явное указание типа строки на входе `AnsiString` (что приведет к конвертации String в AnsiString при вызове) и взятие числового значения буквы `Ord(ch)`.

*P.S. Простой пример, как вы думаете, сколькими способами можно записать в строке русскую букву "А" ? Подсказка, способов больше одного, и у всех будут разные "байты" (и соответственно разные хэши).*

Comment: Ну знаете, в нормальных языка типа java, c# это совместимые типы.

Comment: Повторюсь, строка и число не могут быть просто "совместимыми" типами. Вам необходимо указать как именно вы хотите интерпретировать строку. Ord в помощь. Но опять же, ваш алгоритм возможно не будет работать как надо, если на вход, например, попадет строка из какого-нибудь 4-байтного юникода.

Comment: @Ник `в нормальных языка типа java, c# это совместимые типы.` Как раз таки это не нормально. Если сложить мух с котлетами - на выходе будут и не мухи и не котлеты, а нечто невообразимое. Компилятор правильно делает, что не дает мешать в кучу немешаемое.